# Jquery on button click do timer with progress-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

So I was trying to make a little game but the first step just doesn't work.
This is my code

```
<div id="box1">
        <button id="button">Click Me</button>
        <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>

$('button').click(function() {
var progressBar = $('#progress-bar'),
width = 0;
progressBar.width(width);
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    width += 2.5;
    progressBar.css('width', width + '%');
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
 }, 125)
});

#progress-bar {
width: 0;
background: red;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;   
height: 4px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
#box1 {
height: 100px;
width: 600px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

So when clicking the button there will be a progress-bar at the bottom of box1.
When doing a document ready it works but when using the .click it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When doing a document ready it works but when using the .click it doesn't work.*

It works when you have a `$(document).ready` wrapped around your code because that instructs the javascript engine to wait until all js is fully loaded before trying to execute.

If you don't have the `$(document).ready` and you click before the everything is loaded, then you'll get a console error.

Press F12 to open developer toos and perform the same action, I would suspect you'll see an error in the console.

Comment: Wow i am really stupid... Thanks for your fast reaction! This worked.